# What is preventing hover text (centered) from appearing over image unless pointer moves over bottom half of image?

Tags: html, css, web, hover

CSS code is on top, HTML is on bottom. I want my image to blur and hover text which it is doing but it is only hovering the text when I place cursor near middle of image and bottom half of image. Want when cursor is over any point of image to hover the text respective of image.

```css
.imgtext {      
        color: white;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
        background-position: center;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight: 900;
        top: 40%;
        left:0%;
        bottom:40%;
        right:0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px 14px 14px 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
     
    .pic {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto; 
        display: block;
        width: 450px;
        height: 265x;}

    .pic:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform: scale(1.08);}

    .imgtext:hover {
    -webkit-opacity: 80;
    opacity: 30;}

    .contain {object-fit: contain;}
```

```html
    <!-- Promo Section - "We know Data" -->
    <div class="w3-container" style="padding:36px 16px" id = "about">
    <h3 class="w3-center" style="color:black;font-size:48px;"> <em> </em></h3>
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>. 
      </p>
      <br>
    <p style="color:black;font-size:24px;"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
      <p><a href="#work" class="w3-button w3-black w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off"><i class="fa 
      fa-pencil"></i> </a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m6">
      <!-- Image 0 -->
      <div class="pic">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img src="/Users/andrewramirez/Desktop/Website/Weknowdata.jpeg" class="contain w3-image 
      w3-round-large">
      <span class="imgtext">
      <br>
      <p> COLLABORATION IS KEY </p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to SO! First off: Add this to you CSS `[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }`, change body to `<body outlines="1">` and refresh your page. Now you can exactly see where your elements are.

Comment: After having a good look at your code, some friendly advise: structure your CSS in the same order as your HTML (for as far relevant and possible).  Also, bundle related rules and always use the same order of definition. This will save much time when trying to find errors or simply maintain your code at a later date. That's the reason I rearranged your CSS as I did.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for? I removed and corrected some CSS, removed some `<br>` inside `<div.pic>`. Also corrected the use of `position: relative` and `position: absolute` and `opacity` has a value between [0,1].

You need to check the use in properties with 'vendor-prefixes' as some are no longer required...

The **snippet**

```css
.pic {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto; 
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    height: 265x;
    
    padding: 14px 0; /* so you can see the blurred top/bottom of the image */
}
.pic img {
    display: block;   /* removes some default spacing below */
}
.pic.contain { object-fit: contain }

.pic:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);

    transform: scale(1.08);
}
.pic:hover .imgtext {
    -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.imgtext {
    margin: 0; /* it's a <p>, so remove default margins */

    display: block;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute; /* center in parent */
    top   : 50%;
    left  : 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 

    font-size:24px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}

[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }
```

```html
<body outlines="0">
    <!-- Promo Section - "We know Data" -->
    <div class="w3-container" style="padding: 36px 16px" id="about">
        <h3 class="w3-center" style="color: black; font-size: 48px;">
            <em> </em>
        </h3>
        <div class="w3-row-padding">
            <div class="w3-col m6">
                <br> <br>
                <p>.</p>
                <br>
                <p style="color: black; font-size: 24px;"></p>
                <br> <br>
                <p>
                    <a href="#work" class="w3-button w3-black w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="w3-col m6">
                <!-- Image 0 -->
                <div class="pic">
                    <img class="contain w3-image w3-round-large" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x265">
                    <p class="imgtext">COLLABORATION IS KEY</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```